# How to convert characters to HTML entities using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, symbols, html-entities

I have the following:

```
var text = "Übergroße Äpfel mit Würmern";
```

I'm searching for a Javascript function to transform the text so that every special letter is represented by its HTML entity sequence like this:

```
var newText = magicFunction(text);
...
newText = "&Uuml;bergro&szlig;e &Auml;pfel mit W&uuml;rmern";
```

The function should **not only** escape the letters of this example [but also all of these.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)

How would you achieve that? Is there any existing function out there? (Plain, because a solution without a framework is preferred)

Btw: Yes, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript) but it doesn't address my need.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

With the help of bucabay and the advice to create my own function i created this one which works for me. What do you guys think, is there a better solution somewhere?

```
if(typeof escapeHtmlEntities == 'undefined') {
        escapeHtmlEntities = function (text) {
            return text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666<>\&]/g, function(c) {
                return '&' + 
                (escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable[c.charCodeAt(0)] || '#'+c.charCodeAt(0)) + ';';
            });
        };

        // all HTML4 entities as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html
        // added: amp, lt, gt, quot and apos
        escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable = {
            34 : 'quot', 
            38 : 'amp', 
            39 : 'apos', 
            60 : 'lt', 
            62 : 'gt', 
            160 : 'nbsp', 
            161 : 'iexcl', 
            162 : 'cent', 
            163 : 'pound', 
            164 : 'curren', 
            165 : 'yen', 
            166 : 'brvbar', 
            167 : 'sect', 
            168 : 'uml', 
            169 : 'copy', 
            170 : 'ordf', 
            171 : 'laquo', 
            172 : 'not', 
            173 : 'shy', 
            174 : 'reg', 
            175 : 'macr', 
            176 : 'deg', 
            177 : 'plusmn', 
            178 : 'sup2', 
            179 : 'sup3', 
            180 : 'acute', 
            181 : 'micro', 
            182 : 'para', 
            183 : 'middot', 
            184 : 'cedil', 
            185 : 'sup1', 
            186 : 'ordm', 
            187 : 'raquo', 
            188 : 'frac14', 
            189 : 'frac12', 
            190 : 'frac34', 
            191 : 'iquest', 
            192 : 'Agrave', 
            193 : 'Aacute', 
            194 : 'Acirc', 
            195 : 'Atilde', 
            196 : 'Auml', 
            197 : 'Aring', 
            198 : 'AElig', 
            199 : 'Ccedil', 
            200 : 'Egrave', 
            201 : 'Eacute', 
            202 : 'Ecirc', 
            203 : 'Euml', 
            204 : 'Igrave', 
            205 : 'Iacute', 
            206 : 'Icirc', 
            207 : 'Iuml', 
            208 : 'ETH', 
            209 : 'Ntilde', 
            210 : 'Ograve', 
            211 : 'Oacute', 
            212 : 'Ocirc', 
            213 : 'Otilde', 
            214 : 'Ouml', 
            215 : 'times', 
            216 : 'Oslash', 
            217 : 'Ugrave', 
            218 : 'Uacute', 
            219 : 'Ucirc', 
            220 : 'Uuml', 
            221 : 'Yacute', 
            222 : 'THORN', 
            223 : 'szlig', 
            224 : 'agrave', 
            225 : 'aacute', 
            226 : 'acirc', 
            227 : 'atilde', 
            228 : 'auml', 
            229 : 'aring', 
            230 : 'aelig', 
            231 : 'ccedil', 
            232 : 'egrave', 
            233 : 'eacute', 
            234 : 'ecirc', 
            235 : 'euml', 
            236 : 'igrave', 
            237 : 'iacute', 
            238 : 'icirc', 
            239 : 'iuml', 
            240 : 'eth', 
            241 : 'ntilde', 
            242 : 'ograve', 
            243 : 'oacute', 
            244 : 'ocirc', 
            245 : 'otilde', 
            246 : 'ouml', 
            247 : 'divide', 
            248 : 'oslash', 
            249 : 'ugrave', 
            250 : 'uacute', 
            251 : 'ucirc', 
            252 : 'uuml', 
            253 : 'yacute', 
            254 : 'thorn', 
            255 : 'yuml', 
            402 : 'fnof', 
            913 : 'Alpha', 
            914 : 'Beta', 
            915 : 'Gamma', 
            916 : 'Delta', 
            917 : 'Epsilon', 
            918 : 'Zeta', 
            919 : 'Eta', 
            920 : 'Theta', 
            921 : 'Iota', 
            922 : 'Kappa', 
            923 : 'Lambda', 
            924 : 'Mu', 
            925 : 'Nu', 
            926 : 'Xi', 
            927 : 'Omicron', 
            928 : 'Pi', 
            929 : 'Rho', 
            931 : 'Sigma', 
            932 : 'Tau', 
            933 : 'Upsilon', 
            934 : 'Phi', 
            935 : 'Chi', 
            936 : 'Psi', 
            937 : 'Omega', 
            945 : 'alpha', 
            946 : 'beta', 
            947 : 'gamma', 
            948 : 'delta', 
            949 : 'epsilon', 
            950 : 'zeta', 
            951 : 'eta', 
            952 : 'theta', 
            953 : 'iota', 
            954 : 'kappa', 
            955 : 'lambda', 
            956 : 'mu', 
            957 : 'nu', 
            958 : 'xi', 
            959 : 'omicron', 
            960 : 'pi', 
            961 : 'rho', 
            962 : 'sigmaf', 
            963 : 'sigma', 
            964 : 'tau', 
            965 : 'upsilon', 
            966 : 'phi', 
            967 : 'chi', 
            968 : 'psi', 
            969 : 'omega', 
            977 : 'thetasym', 
            978 : 'upsih', 
            982 : 'piv', 
            8226 : 'bull', 
            8230 : 'hellip', 
            8242 : 'prime', 
            8243 : 'Prime', 
            8254 : 'oline', 
            8260 : 'frasl', 
            8472 : 'weierp', 
            8465 : 'image', 
            8476 : 'real', 
            8482 : 'trade', 
            8501 : 'alefsym', 
            8592 : 'larr', 
            8593 : 'uarr', 
            8594 : 'rarr', 
            8595 : 'darr', 
            8596 : 'harr', 
            8629 : 'crarr', 
            8656 : 'lArr', 
            8657 : 'uArr', 
            8658 : 'rArr', 
            8659 : 'dArr', 
            8660 : 'hArr', 
            8704 : 'forall', 
            8706 : 'part', 
            8707 : 'exist', 
            8709 : 'empty', 
            8711 : 'nabla', 
            8712 : 'isin', 
            8713 : 'notin', 
            8715 : 'ni', 
            8719 : 'prod', 
            8721 : 'sum', 
            8722 : 'minus', 
            8727 : 'lowast', 
            8730 : 'radic', 
            8733 : 'prop', 
            8734 : 'infin', 
            8736 : 'ang', 
            8743 : 'and', 
            8744 : 'or', 
            8745 : 'cap', 
            8746 : 'cup', 
            8747 : 'int', 
            8756 : 'there4', 
            8764 : 'sim', 
            8773 : 'cong', 
            8776 : 'asymp', 
            8800 : 'ne', 
            8801 : 'equiv', 
            8804 : 'le', 
            8805 : 'ge', 
            8834 : 'sub', 
            8835 : 'sup', 
            8836 : 'nsub', 
            8838 : 'sube', 
            8839 : 'supe', 
            8853 : 'oplus', 
            8855 : 'otimes', 
            8869 : 'perp', 
            8901 : 'sdot', 
            8968 : 'lceil', 
            8969 : 'rceil', 
            8970 : 'lfloor', 
            8971 : 'rfloor', 
            9001 : 'lang', 
            9002 : 'rang', 
            9674 : 'loz', 
            9824 : 'spades', 
            9827 : 'clubs', 
            9829 : 'hearts', 
            9830 : 'diams', 
            338 : 'OElig', 
            339 : 'oelig', 
            352 : 'Scaron', 
            353 : 'scaron', 
            376 : 'Yuml', 
            710 : 'circ', 
            732 : 'tilde', 
            8194 : 'ensp', 
            8195 : 'emsp', 
            8201 : 'thinsp', 
            8204 : 'zwnj', 
            8205 : 'zwj', 
            8206 : 'lrm', 
            8207 : 'rlm', 
            8211 : 'ndash', 
            8212 : 'mdash', 
            8216 : 'lsquo', 
            8217 : 'rsquo', 
            8218 : 'sbquo', 
            8220 : 'ldquo', 
            8221 : 'rdquo', 
            8222 : 'bdquo', 
            8224 : 'dagger', 
            8225 : 'Dagger', 
            8240 : 'permil', 
            8249 : 'lsaquo', 
            8250 : 'rsaquo', 
            8364 : 'euro'
        };
    }
```

usage example:

```
var text = "Übergroße Äpfel mit Würmern";
alert(escapeHtmlEntities (text));
```

result:

```
&Uuml;bergro&szlig;e &Auml;pfel mit W&uuml;rmern
```

- **Update1:** Thanks [bucabay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122335/bucabay) again for the || - hint
- **Update2:** Updated entity table with amp,lt,gt,apos,quot, thanks
  [richardtallent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16306/richardtallent) for the hint
- **Update3(in 2014):** [Mathias Bynens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens) created [a lib called 'he'](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he), maybe it serves your need.

Comment: looks good. I'd go for: `escapeHtmlEntities.entityTable[c.charCodeAt(0)] || '#'+c.charCodeAt(0)` so you can catch those charCode's not in entityTable.

Comment: This is a great solution, good balance of capturing all extended Unicode characters but still providing named entities for the most common ones. You should probably add amp, gt, and lt to the entityTable. One small caveat: some older browsers may not support all of the named entities you have in that dictionary.

Comment: @Chris How about making this into a library? :)

Comment: If anyones interested I made a nodejs module out of this, heres [the code](https://gist.github.com/hitautodestruct/5524689).

Comment: Love this answer. I simplified it to to omit the entity table, not match <>\& and you get a great function for 7-bit serialization of html where all you care about is not losing data.

Comment: Another caveat: the code, as written, will not handle Unicode characters U+10000 and greater properly. To handle those, it would be necessary to add code to combine each UTF-16 surrogate pair into a single value.

Comment: Your code is better/more descriptive than this gist (which is similar): https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/6093551. I converted to a singleton and added to my library: https://github.com/centurianii/jsutils

Comment: Why stop at U+2666? Seems arbitrary. For a solution that correctly encodes all except safe & printable ASCII symbols in the input (including astral symbols!), implements all named character references (not just those in HTML4), and works in both Node.js and the browser, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/96656).

Comment: @PleaseStand For what it’s worth, [the _he_ library](http://mths.be/he) handles those just fine.

Comment: @Mathias Bynens create an answer and show a better solution, kid!

Comment: @Chris What do you mean exactly? My comment linked to my answer :)

Comment: @Mathias Bynens i added a link to your lib in my answer.

Comment: Its not converting " into &quot;

Answer (score 63):

All the other solutions suggested here, as well as most other JavaScript libraries that do HTML entity encoding/decoding, make several mistakes:

- They don’t implement [the full list of named character references that browsers support](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html). For example, `htmlDecode('&PrecedesSlantEqual;')` should return `'≼'` ([i.e. `'\u227C'`](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%E2%89%BC)).
- They don’t support encoding astral symbols correctly. For example, [`htmlEncode('')` should return something like `&#x1D306;` or `&#119558;`](http://mothereff.in/html-entities#%F0%9D%8C%86). If an implementation returns two separate entities instead (e.g. `&#xD834;&#xDF06;` or `&#55348;&#57094;`), it is broken.
- They don’t support decoding astral symbols correctly. `htmlDecode('&#x1D306;')` should return `''` and not `'팆'` ([i.e. `'\uD306'`](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%ED%8C%86)).
- They don’t implement [the character reference overrides table listed in the HTML Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#table-charref-overrides). For example, `htmlDecode('&#x80;')` should return `'€'` ([i.e. `'\u20AC'`](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%E2%82%AC)).
- They should perform decoding in a single pass. For example, `htmlDecode('&#x26;amp;')` should return `'&amp;'`, not `&`.

**For a robust solution that avoids all these issues, use a library I wrote called [*he*](http://mths.be/he) for this.** From its README:

> *he* (for “HTML entities”) is a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript. It supports [all standardized named character references as per HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html), handles [ambiguous ampersands](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) and other edge cases [just like a browser would](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#tokenizing-character-references), has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other JavaScript solutions — *he* handles astral Unicode symbols just fine. [An online demo is available.](http://mothereff.in/html-entities)

Comment: item (1),(3), (4) and (5) talk about decoding, not encoding and miss the point of the quesiton. the _he_ library is great anyways, just not really needed for this question. you can look at my solution for a short standalone javascript implementation (encode only).

Answer (score 21):

Using escape() should work with the character code range 0x00 to 0xFF ([UTF-8 range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

If you go beyond 0xFF (255), such as 0x100 (256) then escape() will not work:

```
escape("\u0100"); // %u0100
```

and:

```
text = "\u0100"; // Ā
html = escape(text).replace(/%(..)/g,"&#x$1;"); // &#xu0;100
```

So, if you want to cover all Unicode charachacters as defined on http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html , then you could use something like:

```
var html = text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u00FF]/g, function(c) {
   return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

Note here the range is between: \u00A0-\u00FF.

Thats the first character code range defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html which is the same as what escape() covers.

You'll need to add the other ranges you want to cover as well, or all of them.

**Example**: UTF-8 range with general punctuations (\u00A0-\u00FF and \u2022-\u2135)

```
var html = text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u00FF\u2022-\u2135]/g, function(c) {
   return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

Edit:

BTW: \u00A0-\u2666 should convert every Unicode character code not within ASCII range to HTML entities blindly:

```
var html = text.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
   return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

Comment: Very good point, bucabay... I was handling the simplest case of UTF8 with a quick hack, but this is definitely a more robust solution. Great use of a passed function for handling RegEx replacement, I forgot about being able to do that. Upvoted. Needs a quick fix, however, to add ampersand, less-than, and greater-than to the character range so it can completely replace my code.

Comment: this is way easier than those htmlencode lookup services.  try it as a bookmarklet? `alert(prompt('Enter characters to htmlEncode', '').replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
   return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
}));`

Comment: This approach doesn’t take into account [the character references overrides in the HTML Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#table-charref-overrides). For example, `htmlEncode('\x80')` should not return `&#x80;` or `&#128;`. In fact, it shouldn’t return an HTML entity at all; there is no valid way to represent that character in HTML. [See my answer for more information, and for a better solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/96656)

Comment: That last edit saved the day. Thank you. I was taking some HTML dumped back from the server and trying to open it in a popup window. This came in handy.

Answer (score 8):

The [***he***](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library is the only 100% reliable solution that I know of!

*He* is written by [**Mathias Bynens**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens) - one of the world's most renowned JavaScript gurus - and has the following features :

- Support for [**all standardized named character references**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#named-character-references)
- [**Support for unicode**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)
- Works fine with [**ambiguous ampersands**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands)

---

#### Example use

```
he.encode('foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'); 
// Output : 'foo &#xA9; bar &#x2260; baz &#x1D306; qux'

he.decode('foo &copy; bar &ne; baz &#x1D306; qux');
// Output : 'foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'
```

Comment: question is a native solution without libraries.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
function encodeHTML(str){
 var aStr = str.split(''),
     i = aStr.length,
     aRet = [];

   while (i--) {
    var iC = aStr[i].charCodeAt();
    if (iC < 65 || iC > 127 || (iC>90 && iC<97)) {
      aRet.push('&#'+iC+';');
    } else {
      aRet.push(aStr[i]);
    }
  }
 return aRet.reverse().join('');
}
```

This function HTMLEncodes everything that is not a-z/A-Z.

[**Edit**] A rather old answer. Let's add a simpler String extension to encode all extended characters:

```
String.prototype.encodeHTML = function () {
  return this.replace(/[\u0080-\u024F]/g, 
          function (v) {return '&#'+v.charCodeAt()+';';}
         );
}
// usage
log('Übergroße Äpfel mit Würmern'.encodeHTML());
//=> '&#220;bergro&#223;e &#196;pfel mit W&#252;rmern'
```

Comment: this should be a lot faster then using text.replace(). I love how while(--i) is used instead of for() loop. I'm assuming the theory is that for large text/loops the fast condition test offsets the Array.reverse().join('') outside the loop. Otherwise you would have just used string concatenation?

Comment: Thanks. Decrementing loops are faster than incrementing indeed, it's an optimization step I read about long time ago and I use it most of the time (it's also less code). I'm not sure if the 'reverse'-part weighs out the speed gain. For shorter strings it may be still faster to use aRet[i] = [value] in stead of aRet.push (as is very well explained by "olliej" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value).

Comment: `--i` will equal 0 when reaching the first character. Your condition should be `while (--i >= 0)` or you'll lose the first character of the input string.

Comment: @AliGangji, yes, should've been `i--`, adjusted the answer

Comment: This sample seems flawed for unicode characters; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69588382/1432181 for a better encodeHTML() option

Answer (score 4):

Having a lookup table with a bazillion replace() calls is slow and not maintainable.

Fortunately, the build-in **escape()** function *also* encodes most of the same characters, and puts them in a consistent format (%XX, where XX is the hex value of the character).

So, you can let escape() method do most of the work for you and just change its answer to be HTML entities instead of URL-escaped characters:

```
htmlescaped = escape(mystring).replace(/%(..)/g,"&#x$1;");
```

This uses the hex format for escaping values rather than the named entities, but for storing and displaying the values, it works just as well as named entities.

Of course, escape also escapes characters you don't **need to** escape in HTML (spaces, for instance), but you can unescape them with a few replace calls.

**Edit:** I like bucabay's answer better than my own... handles a larger range of characters, and requires no hacking afterward to get spaces, slashes, etc. unescaped.

Comment: This approach doesn’t take into account [the character references overrides in the HTML Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#table-charref-overrides). For example, `htmlEncode('\x80')` should not return `&#x80;` or `&#128;`. In fact, it shouldn’t return an HTML entity at all; there is no valid way to represent that character in HTML. [See my answer for more information, and for a better solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/96656)

Comment: actually this doesn't work for characters outside the \u00FF range

Answer (score 3):

**I fixed my problem by using** `encodeURIComponent()` **instead of** `escape()`.

This might be the fix for you if the problem happens when sending your string in a URL.

Try this with the phrase ("hi & % ‘")

`escape()` returns

```
"hi%20%26%20%25%20%u2018"
```

Notice the `%u2018` isn't very url friendly and can break the rest of the query string.

`encodeURI()` returns

```
"hi%20&%20%25%20%E2%80%98"
```

Notice the ampersand is still there.

`encodeURIComponent()` returns

```
"hi%20%26%20%25%20%E2%80%98"
```

Finally, all of our characters are properly encoded.

Answer (score 3):

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kritzikratzi/kxsccv97/4/)

here's a tiny stand alone method that:

- attempts to consolidate the answers on this page, without using a library
- works in older browsers
- supports surrogate pairs (like emojis)
- applies character overrides (what's that? not sure exactly)

i don't know too much about unicode, but it seems to be working well.

```
// escape a string for display in html
// see also: 
// polyfill for String.prototype.codePointAt
//   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.codePointAt/master/codepointat.js
// how to convert characters to html entities
//     http://stackoverflow.com/a/1354491/347508
// html overrides from 
//   https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#table-charref-overrides / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript/23831239#comment36668052_1354098

var _escape_overrides = { 0x00:'\uFFFD',0x80:'\u20AC',0x82:'\u201A',0x83:'\u0192',0x84:'\u201E',0x85:'\u2026',0x86:'\u2020',0x87:'\u2021',0x88:'\u02C6',0x89:'\u2030',0x8A:'\u0160',0x8B:'\u2039',0x8C:'\u0152',0x8E:'\u017D',0x91:'\u2018',0x92:'\u2019',0x93:'\u201C',0x94:'\u201D',0x95:'\u2022',0x96:'\u2013',0x97:'\u2014',0x98:'\u02DC',0x99:'\u2122',0x9A:'\u0161',0x9B:'\u203A',0x9C:'\u0153',0x9E:'\u017E',0x9F:'\u0178' }; 

function escapeHtml(str){
    return str.replace(/([\u0000-\uD799]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uFFFF])/g, function(c) {
        var c1 = c.charCodeAt(0);
        // ascii character, use override or escape
        if( c1 <= 0xFF ) return (c1=_escape_overrides[c1])?c1:escape(c).replace(/%(..)/g,"&#x$1;");
        // utf8/16 character
        else if( c.length == 1 ) return "&#" + c1 + ";"; 
        // surrogate pair
        else if( c.length == 2 && c1 >= 0xD800 && c1 <= 0xDBFF ) return "&#" + ((c1-0xD800)*0x400 + c.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00 + 0x10000) + ";"
        // no clue .. 
        else return "";
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to fail when using str = &#9888;&#65039;
Use the encodeHTML (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1354489/1432181) from KooiInc below instead

Answer (score 1):

Just reposting @bucababy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1354491/1037948) as a "bookmarklet", as it's sometimes easier than using [those](http://unicodelookup.com/) [lookup](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/html-character-entities/) pages:

```
alert(prompt('Enter characters to htmlEncode', '').replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
   return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
}));
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for astral symbols (try ``, for example) and it [has some other issues too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/96656). Instead of this bookmarklet, consider using [my online HTML entity encoder/decoder](http://mothereff.in/html-entities).

Comment: @MathiasBynens you have obviously given this more thought and are correct, but it's still not a bookmarklet ;)

Comment: p.s. linking to [astral symbols](http://www.tlg.uci.edu/~opoudjis/unicode/unicode_astral.html) because  I had no idea what @MathiasBynens was talking about

Comment: IMHO adding `http://mothereff.in/html-entities#%s` as a custom search engine to my browser is much easier, but if you insist: `javascript:void (function(){location='http://mothereff.in/html-entities#'+encodeURIComponent(pro‌​mpt('Enter text to HTML-encode:',''))}())`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the JS library [entities](https://github.com/fb55/entities). Using the library is quite simple. See the examples from docs:

```
const entities = require("entities");
//encoding
entities.escape("&#38;"); // "&#x26;#38;"
entities.encodeXML("&#38;"); // "&amp;#38;"
entities.encodeHTML("&#38;"); // "&amp;&num;38&semi;"
//decoding
entities.decodeXML("asdf &amp; &#xFF; &#xFC; &apos;"); // "asdf & ÿ ü '"
entities.decodeHTML("asdf &amp; &yuml; &uuml; &apos;"); // "asdf & ÿ ü '"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution** is posted at phpjs.org implementation of PHP function **[htmlentities](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425)**

The format is `htmlentities(string, quote_style, charset, double_encode)`
Full documentation on the PHP function which is identical can be read [here](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score -1):

I adapted one of the answers from the referenced question, but added the ability to define an explicit mapping for character names.

```
var char_names = {
    160:'nbsp',
    161:'iexcl',
    220:'Uuml',
    223:'szlig',
    196:'Auml',
    252:'uuml',
    };

function HTMLEncode(str){
     var aStr = str.split(''),
         i = aStr.length,
         aRet = [];

     while (--i >= 0) {
      var iC = aStr[i].charCodeAt();
       if (iC < 32 || (iC > 32 && iC < 65) || iC > 127 || (iC>90 && iC<97)) {
        if(char_names[iC]!=undefined) {
         aRet.push('&'+char_names[iC]+';');
        }
        else {
         aRet.push('&#'+iC+';');
        }
       } else {
        aRet.push(aStr[i]);
       }
    }
    return aRet.reverse().join('');
   }

var text = "Übergroße Äpfel mit Würmer";

alert(HTMLEncode(text));
```