# JavaScript htmlentities French

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, model-view-controller, unicode

I have a .NET MVC page with a list of items that each have
`<%: %>` encoded descriptions in the `rel`.
I want to be able to search for all items with a `rel` that contains my search query.

One of the fields has a value with htmlentities `rel='D&eacute;coration'`

I type "Décoration" in the search box, let jQuery search for all elements that have a 'rel' attribute that contains (indexOf != -1) that value:

**no results!**

Why? because `Décoration  != D&eacute;coration`.

What would be the best solution to compare these two? (Has to work for all special accented characters, not just `&eacute;`)

P.S. (I tried escape/unescape on both sides, also tried the trick to append it to a div and then read it as text, this replaces dangerous stuff, but doesn't replace é (it doesn't have to because it's valid in utf-8 anyway))

Comment: Escape your input using Javascript before searching. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript).

Comment: Don't mangle your source code to avoid unwanted formatting. Instead, use the `{}` toolbar button to tag it as code. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Why do you match on a translated string ? Can't you use an identifier that won't change ?

Comment: Humberto, I was hoping for a built in solution but apparently that doesn't really exist. Alvaro, thanks for the hints, i'm pretty new to stackoverflow. While we're at it alvaro, how can I flag humberto's mini-comment as the answer? 

 Nekresh, no I can't do that

Comment: you'll have to wait for @Humberto to add his comment as an answer - then you can accept it. He might pick up on this if we poke him a bit!

Answer (score 2):

Since the `&eacute;` and like are html entities, you can set the html content of a temporary div with the garbled string, and retrive the decoded string using the text content of the element. The browser will do the decoding work for you.

### Using jQuery :

```
function searchInRel(needle) {
    return $('[rel]').filter(function(i,e) {
        var decodedText = $('<div/>').html(e.attr('rel')).text();
        return (decodedText.indexOf(needle) != -1);
    };
}
```

### Using just the DOM :

```
function decodeEntities(text) {
    var tempDiv = document.getElementById('tempDiv');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = text;
    return tempDiv.textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you serve your pages with UTF-8 encoding, you won't need to use entities for all the accented characters. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the html entities.
Just copy the two javascript methods from [HERE](http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424)

```
var decoded = 'Décoration';
var entity = html_entity_decode('D&eacute;coration');
console.log(decoded == entity);
```