# French characters to html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing some French characters in an ajax call to our database. They are expecting É to be passed as `%26Eacute%3B`, é to be passed as `%26eacute%3B`, etc. How can I do this in javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe that any browser has a Javascript transcoding / filtering function that produces XML in a defined charset with the latin-1 chars turned into entities like this.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this [htmlentities()](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425) function. And then [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the result.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rf2rE/