# There is any way to convert this string: "Coordenação" to this: "Coordena&#231;&#227;o" in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I need to make a search but my dada are encoded (in JSON OBJECT) like this: `Coordena&#231;&#227;o` and when i type "Coordenação" on input I didn't find nothing.

I want to know if have any function to convert  `Coordenação`  to `Coordena&#231;&#227;o`

I'm not sure but I think "Coordenação" is UTF-8 encoding and other string is ISO-8859-1

I get the correct string from my oracle database, and it shows correctly in browser, but when i see my code source with my browser, i see my json object with these characters (I'm making a  json object with data from database).

I'm searching for hours how to fix this with other solution but without success, now I'm trying to do convert the data typed on input to match with json data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Don't do that.  JSON objects should not have XML entities.

Comment: where is your data coming from that it looks like that? It feels like there's a missing step when that data is loaded to JSON object. As for the encoding, one is "actual text" encoding, the other is "we don't know which encoding you're using, so we're giving you unicode, with all the non-ascii characters as character entity strings"

Comment: Use Notepad++ to see what happens to the strings. In that program you can change the encondings at will.}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript

Comment: Storing strings with HTML/XML entities in JSON is going about things the wrong way.  Those are, in general, only for I/O, not storage - unless your storage format happens to be XML, which JSON isn't.

Comment: I'm using json only beacause Dynatree component requires this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You @Jonathan. I found the solution in your link.

This function do exact what I want:

```
    function encodeHTML(str) {
        var aStr = str.split(''),
            i = aStr.length,
            aRet = [];

        while (--i) {
            var iC = aStr[i].charCodeAt();
            if (iC < 65 || iC > 127 || (iC > 90 && iC < 97)) {
                aRet.push('&#' + iC + ';');
            } else {
                aRet.push(aStr[i]);
            }
        }
        return aRet.reverse().join('');
    }
```

Comment: As a Brazilian, I've been through this kind of problem too. That's a good source to have a read: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm