# Regex converting & to &amp;

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am developing a small character encoder generator where the user input their text and on the click of a button, it outputs the encoded version.

I've defined an object of the characters that need to be encoded like so:

```
map = {
    '©' : '&copy;',
    '&' : '&amp;'
},
```

And here is the loop that gets the values from the map and replaces them:

```
Object.keys(map).forEach(function (ico) {
    var icoE   = ico.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    raw = raw.replace( new RegExp(icoE, 'g'), map[ico] );
});
```

I am them simply outputting the result to a textarea. This all works fine, however the problem I'm facing is this.

`©` is replaced with `&copy;` however the `&` symbol at the beginning of this is then converted to `&amp;` so it ends up being `&amp;copy;`.

I see why this is happening however I'm not sure how to go about ensuring that `&` is not replaced within character encoded strings.

Here is a JSFiddle for a live preview of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/4m3nw/1/

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `'& ©'.split('').map(function(char) { return map[char] || char; }).join('');`

Comment: Number one problem: What if the original text if `&eacute;`? Should it be replaced, or left alone?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - This will never be the case as this generator is an internal project for work, for those writing copy for blog posts etc.

Comment: "This will never be the case" is the mother of all bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prelude:** Apart from regex, an idea worth considering is something like [this JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript) that already handles html entities. Now, on to the regex question.

**HTML Special Characters, Negative Lookahead**

In HTML, special characters can look not only like `&copy;` but also like `&#8212;`, and they can have upper-case characters.

To replace ampersands that are not immediately followed by a hash or word characters and a semicolon, you can use something like this:

```
&(?!(?:#[0-9]+|[a-z]+);)
```

See the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bH2bJ4).

- Make sure to use the `i` flag to activate case-insensitive mode
- `&` matches the literal ampersand
- The negative lookahead `(?!(?:#[0-9]+|[a-z]+);)` asserts that it is not followed by...
- `(?:#[0-9]+|[a-z]+)` a hash and digits, `|` OR letters...
- then a semicolon.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://regex101.com/r/bH2bJ4)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: I had thought of this but wasn't able to figure out a way. Would it be possible to simply detect the semi-colon only as there sometimes might be an ampersand followed by a word. For example *M&S*

Comment: FYI Added explanation.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Appreciate the explanation too :)

Comment: Just one query, it doesn't seem to be converting stand alone ampersands, for example: `The apple, orange & lemon`. I tried using `/&|& (?.....` but no hope there :/

Comment: Added your example to [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/dH0wO8)... The regex does match that ampersand. Can you please clarify the problem?

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work on standalone ampersnads. It's currently only preventing ampersands that belong to character encoded string from being replaced. Here is a Fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/bgs5m/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55967/discussion-between-zx81-and-lodder).

Comment: I don't think js supports inline flags like `(?i)`

Comment: Thanks for fixing, but I have to say I'm not sure if this is a robust solution altogether. Consider, for example, an input like `"list of firms: ibm; at&t; apple"`.

Comment: @thg435 You're right, the `&` in `at&t;` will not be replaced. That's a whole other level, not something regex can address (unless we had a full list of entities...) Anyhow, apart from that, made a [demo](http://js.do/code/39840) so Lodder can see the replacement is happening correctly... Just not showing on his screen because the browser is showing the `&amp;` directly as `&` :)

Comment: Another idea worth considering is something like [this JS function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript) that already handles html entities. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that since you process the same string you replace the `&`in `&copy;`. If you re-order your map then that seemingly solves the problem. However according to the [ECMAScript specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), this is not a given, so you would be relying on implementation details of the ECMAScript engine used.

What you can do to make sure it will always work is to swap the keys so that `&` is always processed first:

```
map = {
    '©' : '&copy;',
    '&' : '&amp;'
};

var keys = Object.keys(map);
keys[keys.indexOf('&')] = keys[0];
keys[0] = '&';

keys.forEach(function (ico) {
    var icoE   = ico.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    raw = raw.replace( new RegExp(icoE, 'g'), map[ico] );
});
```

Obviously you need to add checks for the `&`'s existence if it isn't always there.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfTc9/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest code change is to reorder your map by putting the ampersand on top.