# Native JavaScript or ES6 way to encode and decode HTML entities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-entities

Is there a native way to encode or decode [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) using JavaScript or ES6? For example, `<` would be encoded as `&lt;`. There are libraries like [`html-entities`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) for Node.js but it feels like there should be something built into JavaScript that already handles this common need.

Comment: There is not a native JavaScript facility. JavaScript the programming language does not really have much to do with HTML, goofy APIs on the String prototype notwithstanding.

Comment: @Pointy I think generally speaking you're right. It just feels like since JavaScript is so widely used on the web, and HTML entities are a common feature of web development, something like this would've made its way into the language over the past decade.

Comment: I think the question would benefit from clearly including the existence of such a function in browsers and nodejs standard library in its scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no native function in the JavaScript API that convert ASCII characters to their "html-entities" equivalent.
Here is a [beginning of a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript) and an [easy trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it) that you may like

Comment: Thanks for the answer (inconvenient as it may) that what I want doesn't exist. Can you post a different solution though? Or just remove the solution link? That linked solution neither decodes HTML entities nor handles `&amp;` vs. numeric encoding.

Answer (score 34):

A nice function using es6 for escaping html:

```
const escapeHTML = str => str.replace(/[&<>'"]/g, 
  tag => ({
      '&': '&amp;',
      '<': '&lt;',
      '>': '&gt;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      '"': '&quot;'
    }[tag]));
```

Comment: +1 for being nice and simple and for working without depending on some 3rd-party code ... though the fallback is unnecessary due to the regexp

Answer (score 8):

#### Roll Your Own <sup>(caveat - use HE instead for most use cases)</sup>

For pure JS without a lib, you can [Encode and Decode HTML entities using pure Javascript](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/188/encode-and-decode-html-entities-using-pure-javascript) like this:

```js
let encode = str => {
  let buf = [];

  for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
  }

  return buf.join('');
}

let decode = str => {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  });
}
```

**Usages**:

```js
encode("Hello > © <") // "&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#32;&#62;&#32;&#169;&#32;&#60;"
decode("Hello &gt; &copy; &#169; &lt;") // "Hello &gt; &copy; © &lt;"
```

**However**, you can see this approach has a couple shortcomings:

- It encodes even safe characters `H` → `&#72;`
- It can decode numeric codes (not in the astral plane), but doesn't know anything about [full list of html entities / named character codes supported by browsers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html) like `&gt;`

---

### Use the [HE Library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) (Html Entities)

- Support for [**all standardized named character references**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#named-character-references)
- Support for [**unicode**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)
- Works with [**ambiguous ampersands**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands)
- Written by [**Mathias Bynens**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens)

**Usage**:

```js
he.encode('foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'); 
// Output : 'foo &#xA9; bar &#x2260; baz &#x1D306; qux'

he.decode('foo &copy; bar &ne; baz &#x1D306; qux');
// Output : 'foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'
```

#### Related Questions

- [How to convert characters to HTML entities using plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/1366033)
- [Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23834738/1366033)
- [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57356698/1366033)
- [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715395/1366033)
- [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915311/1366033)
- [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/1366033)

Answer (score 4):

To `unescape` HTML entities, Your browser is smart and will do it for you

**Way1**

```
_unescape(html: string) :string { 
   const divElement = document.createElement("div");
   divElement.innerHTML = html;
   return divElement.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

**Way2**

```
_unescape(html: string) :string {
     let returnText = html;
     returnText = returnText.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");
     returnText = returnText.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&");
     returnText = returnText.replace(/&quot;/gi, `"`);
     returnText = returnText.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
     returnText = returnText.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
     return returnText;
}
```

You can also use [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#unescape) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unescape)'s unescape method but this ignores `&nbsp;` and handles only `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, and `&#39;` characters.

Answer (score 2):

The reverse (decode) of the answer (encode) @rasafel provided:

```js
const decodeEscapedHTML = (str) =>
  str.replace(
    /&(\D+);/gi,
    (tag) =>
      ({
        '&amp;': '&',
        '&lt;': '<',
        '&gt;': '>',
        '&#39;': "'",
        '&quot;': '"',
      }[tag]),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple htmlEncode and htmlDecode

HTML Encode Function

```
  function encodeHtml(str) {
    let buf = [];

    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test(str[i])))
        buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
      else
        buf.unshift(str[i])
    }

    return buf.join('');
  }
```

HTML Decode function

```
  function decodeHtml(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
      return String.fromCharCode(dec);
    });
  }
```