# How to display HTML code inside a DIV using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have found a similar post, but my situation is different and I think others could benefit if it's in a different post.
My problem is that I have a textarea where people can type anything. I put all the text from the textarea into a variable called "input1" where it is then put into a div to show what the user has typed. my problem is if the user types HTML in the textarea, it will show the HTML in the div. What I have tried is putting the textarea text into the variable "input1" that my system can use, but then from "input1" into "input2" variable, but as a formatted version of the HTML code that will display the HTML but not run it.
So if the user types this:

```
<strong>example text</strong>
```

I would like it to show this:

```
<strong>example text</strong>
```

Not this:

**example text**

Comment: replace all `<` and `>` by `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Please provide the code that you already have. By the sound of it, you're setting innerHtml while you should do something else like produce a div with 
```
font-family: monospace;
white-space: pre;
```
and have input1 value inside

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263803/native-javascript-or-es6-way-to-encode-and-decode-html-entities

Comment: Check out the ```encodeuri()``` and ```decodeuri()``` functions in javascript.

Comment: You can check the answers on this question, it explained in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html

Comment: How do you "inject" the user's input to your ```div```? you can just use ```userInputToShowDiv.innerHTML = userInputText```

Comment: I should have given my code, but its kindof sloppy and has many other things in it. I should also have added that the div still needs to be able to display html, just that the string should not have anything that displays html. I think I understand @Sirko about replacing all the < and > with those, I think I should also change &. is there anything else I would replace using input2 = input1.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/&/g, "&amp;")

Comment: There's no need to replace anything, as the answers to the linked question shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Sirko for pointing me in the right direction, I used what you sent me. Using what I now know I have changed my variables to work.
This is a sample of what I did.

```
input1 = input2.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
```

I have found that you should change the & first, then < and >. because otherwise, it will change the text to a `&lt;` then to a `&amp;lt;`.