# 3rd party lib vs simple function for encoding Html entities to prevent XSS, thoughts?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, xss

I'm in a dilemma to choose an approach for the effective mitigation of XSS in one of my apps and some libs I had forked from GitHub. The thing is to prevent XSS, all we need to do is to escape/encode/sanitize (whatever) the untrusted strings/inputs within the DOM.
I stumbled on a couple of options.

1. Use a 3rd party library - But, this one increases the size, LOC (lines of code) tremendously (exaggerating a little bit here, I know there are lighter libs out there). What I meant is, I don't want another dependency on my app/lib for this thing alone, cuz it's not that critical unless it becomes a pain in the "you know what I mean". My possible candidates are "dompurify", "xss", "sanitize-html". Personally, I'd go with "dompurify", cuz it's simple to use. But what about "xss"? it's like 1 kb lighter than "dompurify", I may need to have a closer look.
2. Next one is more like a workaround, which is to write a hacky JavaScript function maybe like the one in this stackoverflow link, [Native JavaScript or ES6 way to encode and decode HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263803/native-javascript-or-es6-way-to-encode-and-decode-html-entities/57448862#57448862).

Which would be a better way, would this workaround function be enough for preventing the XSS? or shall I go with the adding whole new lib into my codebase?

I know this is kind of a naïve, beginner level question, still you see I had to ask... otherwise my head's gonna be exploding... Need some perspectives.
Please.. I'd love to hear your thoughts guys....
Love this platform.

Comment: _What exactly_ you are trying to insert into the document? HTML structures from outside sources? Or plain text?

Comment: I'm trying to fix some xss issues in some libs, that I'm contributing to. In that case it's basically untrusted inputs from code itself. But in the case of web apps, its just user inputs.

Comment: Hope its clear what I'm trying to convey

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a security expert, so I think it's better to ask the question in security stack exchange.
I think open-sourced 3rd party sanitizer would be the best option, since you don't have to maintain it. Or you can come up with a new creative solution, like sandbox frame it using `<iframe>` and then detect any element present.