# HTML Page utf-8 encoding

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, textarea

I have used

`"<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>"` at the top of my jsp.

UTF-8 coding works fine in all parts of the page except the `<textarea>` field. FYI, I have kept this `<textarea>` filed within a form.

I am testing with the below content in this text area:
****‘Contacts’ AND ™** Trade Mark AND Registered symbol **® AND Double"Quote AND APOSTROPHE'****

But it appears as below in the textarea: 
**âContactsâ AND â¢ Trade Mark AND Registered symbol Â® AND Double"Quote AND APOSTROPHE'**

Please suggest at the earliest. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Reffering to [W3School / HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp):

> Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities.
>
> Characters that are not present on your keyboard can also be replaced by entities.

Based on [Character Entity Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), use `&rsquo;` for ’, `&lsquo;` for ‘,  `&trade;` for ™ and`&reg;` for ®.

Comment: But the thing is the data from the jsp form is received at the server looks like below : 
âContactsâ AND â¢ Trade Mark AND Registered symbol Â® AND Double"Quote AND APOSTROPHE'. Due to this reason, I am unable to use the encoding as you mentioned

Comment: So, you can encode the data before sending it to the server. Here is the hint, how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1354715/6700665