# How to replace HTML code to respective character while parsing using Javascript in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

It's a React-Native application, so I can not go for DOM

I have a HTML as a string let's say,

```
let str = "<p>Research not to discover what&#8217;s already there, but to discover what&#8217;s not.</p>\n",
```

I am able to parse it using Regex

```
str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")
```

But the output of this is,

```
"Research not to discover what&#8217;s already there, but to discover what&#8217;s not.
"
```

which is still have HTML code in it `what&#8217;s` How I can I replace it with `what's`

Comment: Where does this html comes from? Do you have control over it? Can you parse it as JSON?

Comment: @OrDuan I don't have control over it, It's one public rest API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [This answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394814/4711321), but this answer only works for numeric entities, not for things sur as `&amp;`

I guess it depends on how you know what kind of html you might be getting. Otherwise you will have to use a library to decode those HTML entities.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but It's not working for numeric entities also, any other approach you want to suggest?

Comment: The linked answer almost works, you just need to change the regex from `/&#([0-9]{1,3});/gi` to  `/&#([0-9]{1,4});/gi` because hmtl entities can have 4 characters. That being said, since this is a public API and not your own data, I would recommend you to rather use a library for the reasons cleary explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23831239/4711321)

Comment: Yes, I found the solution using the name link, Thankyou @Tony