# Iterating over jQuery $(this).attr('class').split(" ") gives odd results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, iteration

I've got a page where I'm trying to fetch arrays of classes for lots of divs which share a common class. For example:

```
<div class="common lorem ipsum"></div>
<div class="common dolor sit"></div>
<div class="common hello world"></div>
```

I want to fetch each `common` class div and get an Array of it's classes. At the moment, I'm doing it by using this bit of jQuery:

```
$('.common').each(function(index) {
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
  for(var i in classes) {
    alert(classes[i]);
  }
});
```

Looking at the first resulting `classes` variable gives this:

```
classes: Array (3)
0: "common"
1: "lorem"
2: "ipsum"
length: 3
__proto__: Array
```

The problem is that the `for(var i in classes)` seems to be iterating over the `__proto__` Array and delving down into that as well - has anybody ever come across this before? I'm using the latest version of Chrome (6.0.453.1).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
for ( var i = 0, l = classes.length; i<l; ++i ) {
 alert( classes[i] );
}
```

Iterate through an array with a regular for loop, not a `for...in` otherwise it enumerates through the array's properties ( since its still an object and has other properties in addition to the elements inside ).

Comment: +1 avoid gotchas :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154215/what-are-the-most-common-causes-of-errors-in-javascript-and-how-to-fix-them/3154285#3154285

Comment: Also note that for..in is not guaranteed to access the indices in numeric order (see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in))

Comment: true, fortunately it's not an issue here

Comment: ecmascript 5 will also support `Array.forEach()` natively,

Comment: Thanks meder, that's exactly what I was looking for. Now I know!

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other valid answers, since you're already using jQuery, you can take advantage of `jQuery.each`:

```
$.each(classes, function (i, cls) {
    alert(cls);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@meder answered your question just right, i've just wanted to add, that if the order of the enumeration is not important, you can always use this simplified form:

```
for ( var i = classes.length; i--; ) {
  alert( classes[i] );
}
```

It is shorter, and faster.

Comment: Or if you want even faster, use a negative while loop.

Comment: that's one more line of code, for almost **no benefit**. The real issue here is **readability**. This form does well on every field.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to meder's answer...

There is a way of iterating over objects safely without being annoyed by the inherited properties of an object. [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) to the rescue:

```
for(var i in classes) {
  if (classes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    var safeValue = classes[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this used [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_foreach.htm).

I'm not sure what the `(i in this)` double-check against `0-n` weeds out.

```js
var thisp = arguments[1];
for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++){
  if (i in this){
    fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this); // fun(element,index,array)
  }
}
```

Comment: The `i in this` check is because [JavaScript arrays are sparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse).  It's not necessarily true that every integer from 0 to `length` is actually an element of the array.