# How are empty cells stored in a sparse array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory

I have a situation where I may be setting an array cell of a high index without setting any of the cells before it.

```
>>> var arr = [];
undefined
>>> arr[5] = 'value';
"filled"
>>> arr
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "filled"]
```

How is such an array stored in memory? Is there space allocated for each undefined value?

In my actual project, I may be using very large indices. For example, I may set cells 500-800 and 900-1000. I can't use a hash because I need to loop through these non-empty cells and be aware of their index. I want to know if fragmenting the array like this will use up a ton of memory for the empty cells.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, why can't you use `{}`? You can still loop through all properties using a `for (i in obj)` loop.

Comment: Why can't you use a hash table?  If you know the largest index, you can still use a `for` loop.  Either the element is in the hash table, you retrieve and process it, or it is not and you move on to the next loop iteration.

Comment: If space was allocated for each value, then `var foo=[]; foo[999999999] = "uh oh";` would cause a large memory allocation. It doesn't, and so it isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Javascript arrays sparse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse)

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I set only a high index in an array, does it waste memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524067/if-i-set-only-a-high-index-in-an-array-does-it-waste-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strapping onto aefxx's answer, you can still iterate:

```
var obj = {500: "foo",  10923: "bar"};
var max = 0;

for (var key in obj)
   max=key>max?key:(max||key);         // get max key

for (var i=0; i<=max; i++)
   console.log(obj[i]);                // output even the undefined
```

---

As Phrogz commented, it doesn't allocate for undeclared elements of the array.  I'm not certain if that's the case if you explicitly set the element value to undefined (e.g. `arr[somenum] = undefined;`)

Comment: In order to actually see the log prints past (~500) you'll have to adjust the necessary firebug setting.  I think go to `about:config` in the Firefox address bar and set `extensions.firebug.console.logLimit` to at least `10950` (considering the example)

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use a hash because I need to loop through these non-empty cells and be aware of their index.

What's wrong with the `for (x in ...)` language construct?

**EDITED** to accomodate *vol7ron*'s comment:

```
var x = {2: "foo", 999: "bar"};

for ( var n in x ) {
    if ( x.hasOwnProperty(n) ) {
        console.log(n);
        console.log(x[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: a) I suggest that [`hasOwnProperty` is no longer appropriate to use by default](http://phrogz.net/death-to-hasownproperty). b) The problem with this solution is that iterating the keys of an object does not have a guaranteed order, and based on the OP's question it seems probably that JoJo wants/needs to visit them in order.

Comment: @aefxx: I wasn't aware of the `defineProperty` that Phrogz wrote about, though I'm still not 100% sold on it, since as he said there may be problems in some browsers (for me I take the lowest common denominator approach of the major browsers - since IE7/FF3)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably simply store the max index in a variable and the access your map like this :

```
for (var i=0; i<=maxIndex; i++) {
 console.log(myMap[i]);
}
```

Then you'll have the (relative) compacity of the map and the ability to loop through unsetted indexes.