# javascript converting array of ints to array of objects

Tags: javascript, performance

I have an array of ints called `SelectedItems`. I have another array that contains objects that's called `AvailableItems` and that was parsed from json; these `Item` objects have the properties `{ContainerID, ContainerName, ItemID, ItemName}`.

I want to convert `SelectedItems` from an array of ints to an array of `Items` where each `ItemID` is replaced with the `Item` object that corresponds to the `ItemID` in `AvailableItems`. Each `ItemID` in `SelectedItems` is unique.

I started with 2 loops: one that loops through each element of `SelectedItems` but then I find myself looping through `AvailableItems` each time to find the corresponding `ItemID` with the object keys I need to copy into `SelectedItems`.

So basically I built a seemingly very inefficient loop. I was wondering if there was a better way to do it by avoiding a repeated loop inside a loop?

Sample data:

For `AvailableItems`, you have

```
{
  ContainerID: i, 
  ContainerName: 'SomeName', 
  ItemID: j, 
  ItemName: 'SomeOtherName'
}
```

with may be 1,000 objects and then `SelectedItems` is array of ints

```
[23,43,64,34...]
```

Thanks.

Comment: you could filter the second array according to the first , then return the result , with functions like Array.filter , you can check if an element is contained in the first one with Array.indexOf that should be > -1 each time the condition is true.

Comment: @camus: ok, your comment gave the idea on how to redo it better. I copy the AvailableItems array with jquery.extend to a new array called CandidateItems and then I loop through that array: I check to see if the ItemID of each element is in SelectedItems with $.InArray and if it's not I delete that element. At the end of the loop, I assign CandidateArray to SelectedItems and voila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to get any arbitrary `AvailableItem` without looping through the whole array  by just addressing it by its ID(if you have an index-based array where IDs are indexes) then you can go through the `SelectedItems` and check if it exists in `AvailableItems`, and if it does then you convert the `SelecteItem` into an object and add it to some temporary array for later use.

Comment: ok, your answer gave the idea on how to redo it better. I copy the AvailableItems array with jquery.extend to a new array called CandidateItems and then I loop through that array: I check to see if the ItemID of each element is in SelectedItems with InArray and if it's not I delete that element. At the end of the loop, I assign CandidateArray to SelectedItems and voila.

Answer (score 2):

You could put each object in the numeric array `AvailableItems` at the index that matches its `ItemID`.

So you know that the item with an `ItemID` of 5 is at `AvailableItems[5]` instead of having to loop through and find it.

Not sure what effect this will have if you have big gaps between different `ItemID` values, but you can try it and see if it works well.

---

**UPDATE:**

After a quick search, and reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524312/259457), it looks like having gaps between your indexes will not waste a bunch of memory. However, it will affect the result of checking `AvailableItems.length`. If you have an array with one entry, but the index of that entry is 500, then `AvailableItems.length` will return 501, even though there is only one entry in the array.

As long as you don't need to use the `length` function, this solution should work for you.

Comment: ok, I got the idea on how to redo it.  I copy the AvailableItems array with jquery.extend to a new array called CandidateItems and then I loop through that array: I check to see if the ItemID of each element is in SelectedItems with InArray and if it's not I delete that element. At the end of the loop, I assign CandidateArray to SelectedItems and voila