# How does JavaScript create sparse arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

While I don't know the name of this functionality:

```js
a = []
a[57] = "test";

console.log(a.length)
console.log(a[57])
console.log(a)
```

I am in awe that this is possible. Coming from a C background, this behavior is very different than anything like allocating memory. So a few questions:

1. Is Javascript allocating memory for the first 57 "empty" entries in the array?
2. If not, how does Javascript keep O(1) for lookups using fragmented memory addresses?
3. Is a Javascript Array really an Array or just an Object with integers as keys?
4. What is this design pattern called so that I can research it further?

Comment: `C` is a very low level language, `JS` on the other hand is not. It's like a "*do whatever you please*" language and we'll figure out how to do the backend of things. Bear in mind that assigning a variable to the value of another variable you copy the reference and not the value.

Comment: an array is an *exotic object* according to the standard ecma 262.

Comment: Good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524067/if-i-set-only-a-high-index-in-an-array-does-it-waste-memory

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects

Comment: This is possible in just about every dynamic language, and even in C++ with vectors.

Comment: @Xorifelse "Bear in mind that assigning a variable to the value of another variable you copy the reference and not the value."  This only applies to non-primitives as I understand it, not booleans, numbers and strings.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty This is true, obviously. You primarily encounter this within objects, assigning a variable to value to a property and then the mutating begins.. A good way to counter that is by using [pure functions](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-and-functional-programming-pt-3-pure-functions-d572bb52e21c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is Javascript allocating memory for the first 57 "empty" entries in the array?

**1.** No

JS Arrays may or may not be ***dense*** based on the engine, how you construct them, and how you use them afterwards.

Popular engines will create **dense** arrays whenever you construct them with all its elements defined, and no holes.

**Dense** array definition:

```
[0,1,2,3,4];

Array.apply(null, Array(4)); // This is creating an Array expanding the internal Sparse Array as it initial values.
```

**Sparse** Array Definition:

```
[0,,2,3,4];

new Array();

new Array(4);
```

> 2. If not, how does Javascript keep O(1) for lookups using fragmented memory addresses?

**2.** Depends on the Array

For **dense** arrays it will store everything inside the same block of memory.

For **sparse** arrays it will create a hash table and store pointers to each of the elements independently.

> 3. Is a Javascript Array really an Array or just an Object with integers as keys?

**3.** They are a type of `Object`

Arrays are regular Objects, with some properties that let them behave as you would expect.

Accessing elements with integer keys such as `1` (or strings that represent integers such as `"1"`) will retrieve whatever is store under that key. Using non-integers (nor string representations of integers) will still set/retrieve Object properties.

Array `length` is just an attribute of the Object and its value it's not affected by modifying Object properties.

> 4. What is this design pattern called so that I can research it further?

**4.** Not sure