# Javascript (beginner): Performance issue using arbitrary numerical properties?

Tags: javascript

When I do something like this:

```
var o = new Array();
o[20] = true;
o[1000] = true;
o[4000] = true;
```

Is it reasonable to expect that only 3 elements will be allocated or can the implementation decide to suddenly allocate something with 4000 elements?
The reason I'm asking is that when I do this I see in firebug an indication that there are actually 4000 `undefined` in `o`. are they really there?

Comment: It would be reasonable to expect this to error, since `o` is `undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Javascript arrays sparse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse)

Comment: This is more or less the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse.

Comment: Note that `[]` is shorter and faster than `new Array`, and thus almost always preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that we know that `o` is an Array, I can answer you precisely.

**No, the elements will *not be* 'allocated' or 'created'.**

When you make an assignment of an *index property* to an Array object, which is greater than the actual `length` of the array two things happen:

1. The *index named* property is created
2. The `length` property is incremented, to be the `index + 1`

For example:

```
var o = [];
o[4000] = true;

o.hasOwnProperty(0); // false, the property doesn't exist
o.hasOwnProperty(1); // false
o.hasOwnProperty(4000); // true, the property exist
```

As you can see, the `hasOwnProperty` method returns `false` when we test the presence of the `0` or `1` properties, because they don't exist physically on the object, whereas it returns `true` for `4000`, the property that was created.

When Firebug detects that the object being printed in the console is an *array-like* object, it will simply make a loop, showing each of the index values from `0` to `length - 1`.

Firebug detects *array-like* objects simply by looking if they have a `length` property whose its value is an unsigned 32-bit integer (less than `2^32 - 1`), and if they have a `splice` property that is a function, for example, the following object will be detected and printed as an Array on the Firebug's console:

```
console.log({length:3, splice:function(){}});
// Firebug will log: `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`
```

Answer (score 4):

a) That code is not valid. You need either `var o = {}; // object` or `var o = []; // array`.

b) In the first case, the object is sparse. In the second, it *may* depend on the interpreter; in modern browsers it is also sparse. Try `o[99999999] = "hi";` and see how much memory your browser does or does not allocate. If it does not go up by at least 10MB, your arrays are sparse.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I remember Firefox fixing their implementation so that "o[2147483647]" doesn't suddenly use up all machine's memory.

Comment: I don't think it depends on the interpreter. All the JavaScript runtimes will do is make sure that the "length" property remains correct (that is, one larger than the largest non-empty integer-indexed property). The only thing to worry about is the `new Array(n)` constructor when "n" is a large integer, because that function *does* pre-allocate.

Comment: @Pointy I'll change my answer to say "may" depend; I am not personally aware of the implementation of all interpreters. It's possible (if pedantic) to imagine a non-popular or old interpreter with non-sparse behavior.

Comment: @Phrogz fair enough, but "in the wild" I think it's unlikely to be encountered.

Comment: @Pointy, [the Array constructor](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.2.2) *does not pre-allocate*, it just assigns the `length` property if the `n` argument is within the range of unsigned 32-bit integers...

Comment: Really, @CMS?  I've suffered out-of-memory errors on Firefox through buggy code that called `new Array(bigNumber)` accidentally.  That was several years ago, however. (And indeed I just tried it in a Firefox instance, and it's still OK :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this one answers the question.

[Are Javascript arrays sparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse)

And according to that one, arrays are spares, thats is, if you use `for(item in array)` you only get 3 items, not 4000 but if you use array.length it will take the larges integer value and return one larger, look here:

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html

Linkpad will use a `for(item = 0; item < array.length; item++)` and that one will return undefined for any index that is not present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

/*
On the other hand, if you have a **very** large index any array manipulation will have to loop
through each index- it won't skip from one defined item to the the next defined item.

*/

```
var A= [];
A[0]= 'a';
A[10]= 'b';
A[4000000]= 'c';
alert(A.filter(function(itm){
    return itm!= undefined;
}));
```

Comment: Depends on how you loop. If you use `for(i=0; i <a.length; i++)` then yes, it till loop all but if you use `for(i in a) you will only get indexes with a value/item, in this case 3 passes in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript will generate all elements inbetween, always. You may want to use o.length to verify the length of the array. It will return 4000 and not 3.

Comment: This seems to contradict the other answers.

Comment: This is not correct. Yes, "length" is adjusted, but that does not mean that other elements are "filled in" or "generated".  All the interpreter does is set the "length" property to the correct value.