# Aggregating JavaScript array into several arrays with different element lengths?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nomenclature

I have an array with 101 values (representing people aged 0-100).

What would be a preferably fast and simple way of building these aggregated arrays in one go:

```
var input = [55,33,12 .. 98 more]

var output = {   

    //same as input
    i1 = [],

    //0-5, 6-10, 11-15 ... 96-100
    i5 = [],

    //0-10, 11-20, 21-30 ... 91-100
    i10 = [],

    //0-20, 21-40, 41-60 ... 81-100   
    i20 = [],
}
```

*On a side note: Would you name these aggregate arrays by the interval ("i1", "i5") or by the number of groups/elements ("g100", "g20") - what is more intuitive if another programmers comes across these definitions?*

Comment: You don't need to use an object for output: javascript arrays are sparse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse so output can be an array with just four elements (1, 5, 10, 20). In the end there isn't any difference. And surely by interval would be more intuitive.

Comment: @xanatos: But I do use arrays for the actual output? The i1 should have 101 elements; the i5, 20 elements and so on. More specifically I'm interested in the performance of doing this in one loop rather than n separate. (Where n is the number of interval alternatives.)

Comment: It will still be fast! Don't pre-optimize. The only way to do it faster would be to sort the input array and the traverse it by strides of 5, 10 and 20. Otherwhise you'll always have O(n * m) complexity (n = input.length, m = number of intervals)

Comment: Are your ranges intentionally of different sizes?  The first group always has one more element than the rest of them (e.g. 0-5 has six possible values whereas 6-10, 11-5, ... have only five).

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse results of the aggregation to calculate the next array.

```
// sums up each n numbers from the input array
//
function groupSum(inarray, n) {
    var outarray = [];
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inarray.length; i++) {
        sum += inarray[i];
        if (i % n == n - 1) {outarray.push(sum); sum = 0;}
    }
    // add the last element
    if (i % n != 0) { outarray.push(sum); }

    return outarray;
}

var input = [55, 33, 12, 98, /* more numbers here */ 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 7];

var output = {};
output.i1 = input;
output.i5 = groupSum(output.i1, 5);
output.i10 = groupSum(output.i5, 2);
output.i20 = groupSum(output.i10, 2);
```

Note that, as xanatos said, performance is not really of big concern here.

PS1: was not sure if you were trying to make output an object (as in this code) or 2D array.

PS2: since your first group always has 1 more element, you might need to adjust the code a bit for this special case.