# Putting items in JavaScript arrays on arbitrary indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Javascript arrays sparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse)

Is the following "safe" in JavaScript? (as in, can be expected to work reliably on all JavaScript engines)

```
a = [];
a[100] = "hello";

a[100] == "hello"; // should be true
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse

Comment: Yes, it will work everywhere. But if you don't actually need array-specific functionality, like `.length`, use an object instead: `var a = {};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Arrays in JavaScript are sparse and your code is expected to work in all JavaScript implementations.

You can get into requirements in the section 15.4 of the [specification(PDF)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Short summary: array is special object that have length property adjusted when one adds elements at properties with numeric names (like `a[123]="test"). Other methods like join  take length into account duuring operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why wouldn't it work? Its perfectly acceptable syntax.

Comment: Syntactically yes, but I was just wondering if initializing items at arbitrary indices was well-defined behavior in JavaScript.

Comment: @rfw, it is well defined in that it is valid in the language, but how the implementation is done may vary.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1510842/362536

Comment: There are lots of statements that are "acceptable syntax" that will just not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can even assume

```
a[100] === "hello"; // will return true
```