# In nodeJs is there a way to loop through an array without using array size?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have

```
myArray = ['item1', 'item2']
```

I tried

```
for (var item in myArray) {console.log(item)}
```

It prints
    0
    1

What I wish is to have 
    item1
    item2

Is there any other syntax that works without using

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not use a normal `for` loop or the `.forEach()` function?

Comment: Writing it as `for (var propertyName in myArray)` would make the issue with the observed behavior more clear. In any case, for a higher-order construct, see [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) but note it has a number of implications that make it *different* from either of the above forms. (The differences between the forms are covered by *many* duplicates.)

Comment: @Pointy because the normal loop is uselessly complicated : why do I need to calculate the size of an array whereas the interpreter can know it. forEach() ? Well that's my question is there any other syntax so I'll try thanks.

Comment: Looking at the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), there's a bunch of methods to do this.

Comment: @user310291 `length` *doesn't* "calculate" the size of the array. The length of an array is an intrinsic value of the Array type.

Comment: Even if `length` was calculated, you could just cache it: `for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++)`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var myArray = ['1','2',3,4]

myArray.forEach(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Still uses array length under the hood. But it could simply be that the OP doesn't want to refer to the length explicitly.

Comment: @canon, you literally suggested `forEach()` (after I answered here) in the comment for another answer.

Comment: Note that if you add `myArray[123] = '6'` you will get a totally different result using `Array.forEach` than when using `for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)` syntax.

Comment: Oh, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397746/in-nodejs-is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-an-array-without-using-array-size/29397769#comment46971797_29397847). I originally thought you meant [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397746/in-nodejs-is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-an-array-without-using-array-size/29397769#comment46971853_29397769). That was mainly because, if reaching for an array method at all, `map()` wouldn't be the appropriate analog.

Answer (score 75):

What you probably want is [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), a relatively new construct built for the express purpose of enumerating the *values* of iterable objects... as distinct from [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), which enumerates *property names* (presumably<sup>1</sup> numeric indices in the case of arrays). Your loop displayed unexpected results because you didn't use the property names to get  the corresponding values via [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)... but you could have.

```js
const array = ["a","b","c","d"];

for (let value of array) {
  console.log(value);
}

for (let propertyName in array) {
  let value = array[propertyName];
  console.log("propertyName: %o, value: %o", propertyName, value);
}
```

```html
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------><script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><script>console.config({timeStamps:false,maximize:true})</script>
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> **Unfortunately**, someone may have added [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) to the array or its prototype chain which are *not* numeric indices... or they may have assigned an index leaving unassigned indices in the interim range. The issues are explained pretty well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/621962). The main takeaway is that it's best to loop explicitly from `0` to `array.length - 1` rather than using `for...in`.</sub>

To address [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397746/in-nodejs-is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-an-array-without-using-array-size/29397769#comment46971704_29397746) (emphasis mine):

> [...] why do I need to **calculate the size** of an array whereas the interpreter can know it[?]

`Array.length` is not calculated on the fly; it's updated whenever the length of the array changes. You're not going to see performance gains by avoiding it (apart from caching its value rather than repeatedly accessing the property). Here's [a test of various constructs used to perform a sum operation on an array of 1,000 numeric elements](https://jsbench.me/pylub9rrra/1) (bigger bars are better).

[image: Bar chart depicting operations per second (higher is better) for a sum operation using different constructs, i.e.: for..in at 12,000 ops/s, for..of at 24,000 ops/s, Array.prototype.reduce() at 36,000 ops/s, for at 78,000 ops/s, and for (length cached) at 112,000 ops/s.]

Feel free to fork the test and try different inputs, methods, etc.

Answer (score 6):

To print 'item1' , 'item2', this code would work.

```
var myarray = ['hello', ' hello again'];

for (var item in myarray) {
    console.log(myarray[item])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In ES5 there is no efficient way to iterate over a *sparse* array without using the length property. In ES6 you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Take this examples:

```js
'use strict';

var arr = ['one', 'two', undefined, 3, 4],
    output;

arr[6] = 'five';

output = '';
arr.forEach(function (val) {
    output += val + ' ';
});
console.log(output);

output = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output += arr[i] + ' ';
}
console.log(output);

output = '';
for (var val of arr) {
    output += val + ' ';
};
console.log(output);
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="//gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

All array methods which you can use to iterate safely over *dense* arrays use the `length` property of an object created by calling `ToObject` internaly. See for instance the algorithm used in the `forEach` method: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18
However in es6, you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) safely for iterating over sparse arrays.

See also [Are Javascript arrays sparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse).

Answer (score 3):

This is the natural javascript option

```js
var myArray = ['1','2',3,4]

myArray.forEach(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

However it won't work if you're using **await** inside the forEach loop because forEach is not asynchronous.
you'll be forced to use the second answer or some other equivalent:

```js
let myArray = ["a","b","c","d"];
for (let item of myArray) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Or you could create an asyncForEach explained here:

> https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Answer (score 1):

Use Iterators...

```
var myarray = ['hello', ' hello again'];
processArray(myarray[Symbol.iterator](), () => {
    console.log('all done')
})
function processArray(iter, cb) {
    var curr = iter.next()
    if(curr.done)
        return cb()
    console.log(curr.value)
    processArray(iter, cb)
}
```

More in depth overview: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Answer (score 1):

```
    var count=0;
    let myArray = '{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c","4":"d"}'
    var data = JSON.parse(myArray);
    for (let key in data) {
      let value =  data[key]; // get the value by key
      console.log("key: , value:", key, value);
      count = count + 1;
    }
   console.log("size:",count);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the built-in Javascript function called map.  .map() will do the exact thing you're looking for!

Comment: I would think `forEach()` would be the more direct match than a function which creates a new array...