# Maintaining a key index steady

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, indexing

I have an object used as index.

```
const index= {};
```

I use a counter to get a new key:

```
var key=0; 
function getNewKey(){
   return ++key;
}
```

Then I can add object to `index`:

```
function addObject(object){
    const key= getNewKey();
    index[key]= object;
    return key;
}
```

But, like that, if I remove objects in index, and add new ones, there will be holes, and the key may become big.

So I would like to know if there was patterns for this kind of problem, which often appears.

Comment: You can use an array for this. why do you want to use a plain object since the keys are indexed numbers?

Comment: yes but the problem is the same

Comment: There will be no holes if you use `delete index[key]` to remove objects. And what is the problem with larger keys?

Comment: problems could be an integer overflow, but before that I think that it is preferable to maintain a reasonable key size. If there is a lots of adds/removes, the key will increase fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array as your index.

```
const index= [];
```

Removing an object can then be done by setting the corresponding array entry to `undefined`.

```
function removeObject(key) {
    index[key] = undefined;
    if( key == index.length - 1 ) index.pop();
}
```

A new object is placed in the next free slot of the array, which can be found with the `indexOf` method.

```
function addObject(object) {
    const pos = index.indexOf(undefined)
    const key = pos == -1 ? index.length : pos;
    index[key]= object;
    return key;
}
```

With this approach the key size will be minimal. Since array implementations are usually sparse as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse), also the memory usage will be as small as possible.