# What's the difference between declared "undefined" value and undeclared "undefined" value?

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please explain what's the difference between the first example and the second example, please?

What's the difference between declared "undefined" value and undeclared "undefined" value?

**Code**

```
var arr = new Array(4);
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b";
arr[2] = undefined; //insert undefined here!
arr[3] = "d";
console.log("arr[2] is " + arr[2]); //yes, it is undefined!

arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    console.log(index + ":" + value);
})

console.log("====================")

var arr = new Array(4);
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b";
//I don't insert undefined to arr[2] in this case.
arr[3] = "d";
console.log("arr[2] is " + arr[2]); //yes, it is undefined!

arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    console.log(index + ":" + value);
})
```

**Log**

```
arr[2] is undefined
0:a
1:b
2:undefined
3:d
====================
arr[2] is undefined
0:a
1:b
3:d
```

**Additional Example**

```
var arr = new Array(4);
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b";
arr[2] = undefined; //insert undefined here!
arr[3] = "d";
console.log("arr[2] is " + arr[2]); //yes, it is undefined!

var i = 0;
var max = arr.length;
for(i; i < max; i++) {
console.log(i + ":" + arr[i]);
}

console.log("====================")

var arr = new Array(4);
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b";
//I don't insert undefined to arr[2] in this case.
arr[3] = "d";
console.log("arr[2] is " + arr[2]); //yes, it is undefined!

var i = 0;
var max = arr.length;
for(i; i < max; i++) {
console.log(i + ":" + arr[i]);
}
```

**Log**

```
arr[2] is undefined
0:a
1:b
2:undefined
3:d
====================
arr[2] is undefined
0:a
1:b
2:undefined
3:d
```

Comment: one is initialized (in JS we say 'declared') but undefined; one isn't initialized and undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Javascript arrays sparse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse)

Comment: @Ramanlfc this is not a duplicate of that question. it's clear OP understands this aspect

Comment: @Jeremy Could you explain why forEach doesn't visit when a value is undeclared undefined but visits when a value is declared undefined?

Answer (score 2):

> Could anyone please explain what's the difference between the first example and the second example, please?

In the first example:

```
var arr = new Array(4);
```

creates an array with length 4, it has no elements.

Then a value is assigned to indexes 0 to 3 using direct assignment:

```
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b";
arr[2] = undefined; //insert undefined here!
arr[3] = "d";
```

which creates properties 0 to 3. *undefined* is assigned to `arr[2]`. *forEach* iterates over elements that exist, so you see the result from all 4 elements, each with a value.

In the second example, you do not assign a value to `arr[2]`. When accessing a non–existent property of an object (noting that Arrays are Objects), the *undefined* value is returned, e.g.

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.foo) // undefined
```

When looping over the properties with *forEach*, non–existent properties aren't visited so there is no output for `arr[2]`. This is in contrast to *for* loops, which are generally written to visit all properties from 0 to `length - 1` and hence return values for all properties in that range, whether they exist or not.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the differencd between foreach and for. now im clear!

Comment: @Hayatomo—you may wish to review the [*forEach* polyfil on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill), which follows the steps in ECMA-262 and has an own property test at step 7.b (which is step 8.b. in [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) and 6.b in [*ECMAScript 2017*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach)).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are not arrays in common sense. In most languages arrays (a.k.a. vectors) are contiguous areas in memory. But in JS they are rather sparse containers - some elements may not exist.

In fact arrays in JS are just objects (key/value maps) with the difference that integer keys are allowed:

```
var arr = {}; // object (key/value map), not array, sic!
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b"; 
// arr[2] deliberately omitted
arr[3] = "d";
console.log("arr[2] is " + arr[2]); // it is undefined
```

You can even add non-integer keys to JS arrays:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 0;
arr["zero"] = "zero";
```

This proves that arrays are objects under the hood.

When you try to get from a container (object or array) value of non-existent key it returns `undefined` value. By ECMAScript specification.

`arr[2] = undefined` assigns that value to key 2.

`delete arr[2]` removes that key and its value.

Comment: "with the difference that integer keys are allowed" --- this is vague (and not 100% correct): 1. They are still converted to strings 2. Objects can also hold "numeric" keys.

Comment: Whether arrays are "contiguous in memory" or not isn't relevant. Integer keys are allowed on all objects, not just arrays (which, as you say, are just Objects with a special *length* property and some handy inherited methods that are mostly generic and can be applied to other objects too).

Comment: @RobG " Integer keys are allowed on all objects". Negative in ES5, try this https://jsfiddle.net/ok3b4tg8/ . Indexes in objects are strictly strings. Even you will use numeric value it will be converted to string. `Object.keys()` cannot return anything but vector of strings.

Comment: "Even you will use numeric value it will be converted to string" --- that's correct. And now it contradicts with yours "In fact arrays in JS are just objects (key/value maps) with the difference that integer keys are allowed"

Comment: @c-smile—integer is not a type in javascript. I understood your original statement "*…with the difference that integer keys are allowed…*" to mean integers allowed as keys, i.e. strings (noting that integers of type string and number are largely interchangeable in ECMAScript except for addition).

Comment: @RobG "string and number are largely interchangeable " not always. 
Indexes in Arrays must be integers (Number.isInteger(value) -> true). Otherwise they are not indexes but keys, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/ujxp186b/

Comment: @c-smile—please don't misquote when replying: "***…integers** of type string and number are largely interchangeable*…", which also means "not always".