# In the context of Immutable.JS, what does "dense" mean?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/):

> Lists are ordered indexed dense collections, much like a JavaScript Array.

What does "dense" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the opposite of [*sparse* arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510778/1048572). In a dense array, there exists a property with a value for every index between `0` and `arr.length`.

Comment: arr.length exclusive. Those are informal definitions, correct? Can arrays with limited number of holes still be dense?

Comment: @le_m I'm not sure whether "between" carries any notion of in/exclusiveness, but yes `[0, arr.length[`. No, a dense array cannot have *any* holes.

Comment: @le_m Yes, informal, I don't know of any standards body that would define them. And of course, when an engine use a dense C array to represent a sparse JS array with few holes, terminology gets weird.

Comment: I was referring to the later case, but you are probably right that - due to different and constantly evolving heuristics used by engines to determine the underlying datastructure of an array - we should stick to the simple implementation agnostic definition of "dense" as having no holes. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

An object with indices from 0 to N, where every index in the range is defined, is dense.

On the other hand, an object with (e.g.) only indices 1, 100, 200, 400, 450, 500 populated is sparse, since not every index is used.

Comment: Then the part *much like a JavaScript Array* is a bit misleading as javascript arrays are not inherently dense. :-/