# Find length (size) of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple question that I'm struggling with for some reason.

Why does the below return `undefined`?

```
var testvar={};
testvar[1]=2;
testvar[2]=3;
alert(testvar.length);
```

**edit** I originally typed `testvar[1].length`.  I knew this to be an error.  I meant `testvar.length`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Because `2` isn't an array, it's a number. Numbers have no length.

Perhaps you meant to write `testvar.length`; this is also undefined, since objects (created using the `{ ... }` notation) do not have a length.

Only arrays have a length property:

```
var testvar = [  ];
testvar[1] = 2;
testvar[2] = 3;
alert(testvar.length);    // 3
```

Note that Javascript arrays are indexed starting at `0` and are not necessarily [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) (hence why the result is 3 and not 2 -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value/614255#614255) for an explanation of when the array will be sparse and when it won't).

Answer (score 5):

testvar[1] is the value of that array index, which is the number 2.  Numbers don't have a length property, and you're checking for 2.length which is undefined.  If you want the length of the array just check testvar.length

Answer (score 3):

Integer has no method length. Try string

```
var testvar={};
testvar[1]="2";
alert(testvar[1].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `length` is undefined you can use:

```
function count(array){

    var c = 0;
    for(i in array) // in returns key, not object
        if(array[i] != undefined)
            c++;

    return c;
}

var total = count(array);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
obj={};

$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    console.log(key+ ' : ' + value); //push the object value
});

for (var i in obj) {
    nameList += "" + obj[i] + "";//display the object value
}

$("id/class").html($(nameList).length);//display the length of object.
```

Comment: Please don't just post code without any explanation. Anyway, this code does not seem to have anything to do with what was beeing asked in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

```
       var mode = [];
                $("input[name='mode[]']:checked").each(function(i) {
                    mode.push($(this).val());
                })
 if(mode.length == 0)
                {
                   alert('Please select mode!')
                };
```

Comment: "*Why does the below return 'undefined'?*"

Answer (score -3):

```
var array=[];

array.push(array);  //insert the array value using push methods.

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
    nameList += "" + array[i] + "";          //display the array value.                                                             
}

$("id/class").html(array.length);   //find the array length.
```