# Find length of an array in jquery getting wrong result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have javascript code like below to get the size of an array,

```js
var testvar = [  ];
testvar[1] = 2;
testvar[200] = 3;
alert(testvar.length);    //201
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj9p99sf/)**

But the code alerts `201` insted of getting the size `2`,Why?

**I need to get the count of total elements in that array.**

Comment: the length property says nothing about the number of defined values in the array.

Comment: You can follow this link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317298/find-length-size-of-an-array-in-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript count of array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901950/javascript-count-of-array-elements)

Comment: the array.length value calculates the length just by adding 1 to the last index. That is the reason you get 201 instead of 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to really find the length of your array despite doing such things :

```
alert(Object.keys(testvar).length);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqsf45a/

note that `Object.keys()` is not avaiable in IE < 9.
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys for workarounds

Comment: This gives you neither the length of the array (which **is** `testvar.length`) nor the number of elements in the array. `testvar.x = 1` doesn't change the number of elements in the array, but it does change the value reported by your solution.

Comment: @zeroflagL It does however answer the op's question. Note how Enjoyted said 'find the length of *your* array'

Comment: Object.keys has compatibility issues with IE. IE support starts in IE9.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 8):

Because you are setting a value at index 200 with `testvar[200] = 3`. 
The `length` property will be the last index of the array + 1.

For getting the total count of elements, you can use the following for example:

```
function countElements(arr) {
    var numElements = 0;
    for ( var indx in arr ) {
        numElements ++;
    }
    return numElements;
}
```

Comment: I need to get the count of total elements in that array. Is it possible?

Comment: @Shijin the above code does that for you. It returns the number of elements in the array

Comment: What a **horrible** way of solving this. Try `testvar[1000000000] = 5;` and watch your browser freeze while using your function. `Object.keys(testvar).length;` is the way to go.

Comment: what if the array is : arr[1], arr[200], arr['a211'], isNaN is pointless and wrong, ain't it ?

Comment: @devqon Removed the downvote. Still don't see the point of your function though.

Comment: @Enjoyted the `isNaN` is for browser compatibility. Chrome and Safari add non-numeric elements to the loop @Bas this also works in legacy browsers, if those aren't an issue then indeed the `Object.Keys` is the way to go

Comment: Well after testing, I still hold my point. Just test for yourself! Removing the 'if' part would make your script correctly work even tho Object.keys() is the native way of doing it.
Your current script doesn't replicate Object.keys(). http://jsfiddle.net/mvf9po3a/

Comment: @Enjoyted it seems you are right, Chrome at least handles it correctly

Comment: on FF and IE8 too as far as I tested ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript allows *sparse* arrays, which means you can have an array with two elements, but the length of the array is pegged to the *index* for the last element, and is achieved by adding 1 to the last index. So if your last index is 200, the length reported for the array will be 201.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This should get the correct number of elements:

```
testvar.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot assign values this way. What you just did is create an array which has 200 length (including 0).

You should probably use an object for what you're doing instead.

I believe what you try to do only works in PHP arrays

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> the length property says nothing about the number of defined values in the array.

To get the count of defined items you could use something like this

`var count = array.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var testvar = [  ];
testvar[1] = 2;
testvar[200] = 3;

var size = testvar.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length;

console.log(size);
```

output

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way, its working.

```
<script>
 var testvar = new Object();
 testvar["1"] = 2;
 testvar["200"] = 3;

 Object.size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
 };

 // Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(testvar);
 alert(size);
 </script>
```

Comment: nice copypasta ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array

Answer (score -1):

Because you are adding an item at index 200, which will resolve in the array being padded up with a lot of undefined values, if you want to find all non undefined values you could use:

```
var sum = testvar.reduce(function(sum) { return sum+1; }, 0); // 2
```

---

JavaScript doesn't support associative arrays, but you can use objects instead:

```
var a = {};
a[1] = 1;
a[200] = 1;

// To get the length is a little tricky
var length = Object.keys(a).length; // 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, how the prior answer said. Javascript arrays are null based, and they have a length with starts at 0, every time.

What do you want to archive? Getting only the length of a list you have?

Why do you set the 3 to position 200? Is that needed for your code?

What you can do is:

```
var testvar = {'1': 2, '200': 3};

function length(arr) {
  var c = 0;
  for(prop in arr) {
     if(typeof arr[prop]=='number')
       c++;
  }
  return c;
}
length(testvar);
```

This gives you the correct length!