# Looping to create object Keys and Values in Javascript from 2D arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays, one which holds the keys and one which holds arrays, each array containing values. I would like to make an array of objects, where each object pairs the keys and values. To do this, I created an array, and I am now trying to create and fill objects before pushing them into the array. My code looks similar to this:

```
var keys = [key1, key2, key3];
var values = [
                [A-value1, A-value2, A-value3],
                [B-value1, B-value2, B-value3],
                [C-value1, C-value2, C-value3]
             ];

var arrayOfObjecs = [];
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    var obj = {
    for(var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++){
            keys[j] : values[i][j];
    }
    };
    arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
}
```

In the end, I would like for my arrayOfObjects to look like this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
                        {
                         key1 : A-value1,
                         key2 : A-value2,
                         key3 : A-value3
                        },
                        {
                         key1 : B-value1,
                         key2 : B-value2,
                         key3 : B-value3
                        },
                        {
                         key1 : C-value1,
                         key2 : C-value2,
                         key3 : C-value3
                        }
                     ];
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290131/javascript-how-to-create-an-array-of-object-literals-in-a-loop) is similar to what I want to do, yet it won't allow me to loop a second time within the object.

Comment: took me a few edits, but my answer should work now :)

Comment: See similar question [Easiest way to interate over a complex JSON object via Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192051/easiest-way-to-interate-over-a-complex-json-object-via-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is in fact about the object properties square bracket notation :
 using object[propertyname] is the same as using object.*propertyname*.

```
var myObj  = {};
myObj['x'] = 12;
console.log(myObj.x);  -->> prints 12
```

Now in your code :

```
var arrayOfObjects = [];
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    var obj = {};
    for(var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++){
         obj[keys[j]] = values[i][j];  
      }
    arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
}
```

In reply to 'it does weird things' : this code works.

with this input :

```
var keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
var values = [
            [12,112, 1112],
            [31, 331, 3331],
            [64, 65, 66]
         ];
```

the output is :

```
   {   {key1: 12, key2: 112, key3: 1112},  
       {key1: 31, key2: 331, key3: 3331},   
       {key1: 64, key2: 65, key3: 66}        }
```

fiddle is here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/fyt8A/

Comment: That does weird things… you're iterating over values and keys at the same time

Comment: it does just what is expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17353800/1 did :-) Your edit hasn't been loaded when I commented.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var arrayOfObjecs = values.map(function(value_set){
                                  var obj = {}; 
                                  for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ )
                                        obj[keys[i]]=value_set[i];      
                                  return obj;})
```

map is a great function for looping over arrays

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

> ```
> …
>     var obj = {
>     for(var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++){
>         keys[j] : values[i][j];
>     }
>     };
> …
> ```

That's a syntax error. You can't put the for-loop in the middle of the object literal. Instead, create the empty object in one step and then fill it with the properties by assignment (using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)) in the loop:

```
…
    var obj = {};
    for(var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++){
         obj[keys[j]] = values[i][j];
    }
…
```