# Loop each jQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var arrayInstSaude = new Array();
$("input[name='uniSaudePrj']:checked").each(function(){
    arrayInstSaude[$(this).val()]=$(this).val();
});
```

For some reason it gives me a messed array.
Exemple:

- if I check 1 element value eq 1. It gives me the arrayInstSaude length equal 2.
- if I check 2 elements value eq 2. It gives me the arrayInstSaude length equal 3.
- if I check 3 elements value eq 5. It gives me the arrayInstSaude length equal 6.
- if I check 4 elements value eq 6. It gives me the arrayInstSaude length equal 7.
- if I check 5 elements value eq 7. It gives me the arrayInstSaude length equal 8.

If I do that for 5 elements:

```
for (var i = 1; i <=arrayInstSaude.length; i++) {
     alert(arrayInstSaude[i]);
}
```

I will have 1,2,undefined,undefined,5,6,7,undefined, while it was expected to have 1,2,5,6,7.
Someone know what is going on?
Thanks!

Comment: Array indexes start from 0. If you create `array[1]`, the length is 2 because it has `array[0]` and `array[1]`.

Comment: When you create `arrayInstSaude[5]` it automatically creates 3 & 4, but with no values.  It can't just leave them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are always contiguous.
The length is simply the highest index plus one.

It sounds like you want a regular object that happens to have numeric keys (and no length).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for (var i = 1; i <=arrayInstSaude.length; i++) {
     alert(arrayInstSaude[i]);
}
```

with

```
for (var i in arrayInstSaude) {
     alert(arrayInstSaude[i]);
}
```

Consider reading this [discussion by olliej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614255/18192).

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is enough for my propouse:

```
var arrayInstSaude = new Array();                
var k=0;
$("input[name='uniSaudePrj']:checked").each(function(){                    
    arrayInstSaude[k]=$(this).val();
    k++;
});
```

It was important to observe that the length is the highest index plus one. So, to retrieve the elements we could use

```
for(k=0;k<arrayInstSaude.length;k++){
    alert(arrayInstSaude[k]);
}
```

Because we know that the last element is allways empty.