# JavaScript items disappearing from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called objs that holds all of my application objects. Objects get added and removed from this list depending upon what happens in the application.

I am having this problem where some objects disappear (or are overwritten) only sometimes. If I step through the add and remove functions, the app always runs as it should, however many times when it is run without the debugger, one or two objects that were added to the end of the list disappear from the list.

objects are added to the array like this:

```
this.objs[this.objs.length]=obj;
```

and are removed from the array like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<this.objs.length;i++)
     if(this.objs[i]==obj)
           return this.objs.splice(i,1);
```

I put this code at the end of my add and remove functions:

```
console.log("add! ");
console.log(this.objs);
```

Linked is an image of a console log during a session where an object dissapeared: http://ilujin.com/error.png

The first 4 objects in the list shown at the top should remain in the list throughout the session, but the object at index 3 (highlighted in red), gets overwritten by the next object that gets added (highlighted in blue).

The other weird thing is that the second list shown already has all of the changes (4 objects removed and 1 added), even though the remove function has only been called once and the add function not at all.

This makes me conclude that the problem is timing - if one add hasn't finished before the next add is called, the first one will be overwritten. And all of the console prints are the same because they all happen before the console can read and print.

Does this makes sense? For some reason I thought JS never ran parallel code and only moved on to a new function when the last function finished. Is the problem that I'm using the length of the objs list as the new index when I add to the list?

How can I fix this issue? I can't figure it out, and the debugger and console have proven  useless.

Here is the app: http://iioengine.com/neuro/study2.htm

you only need to enter an id and see if the instructions pop up. If they do, than its working and refresh. If they don't, that means that the Text Object got overwritten.

Comment: can you replicate this behavior in a jsfiddle?

Comment: JavaScript is indeed single-threaded

Comment: There is not enough code here, and your log is not detailed enough for us to tell what's going on.  Please either post a more complete code example, or (ideally) create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem, and post the link here.

Comment: Why are you adding item like that: `this.objs[this.objs.length]=obj`... Isn't `this.objs.push(obj)` better?

Comment: It's easier to read and less code to execute. Speed stays [about the same.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2366118/283863)

Comment: Since `splice` mutates the array itself, you would have to recalculate your loop state. Because you don't, your loop works in a way you don't expect it to – at least I would boldly guess that this is the problem.

Comment: there's no need to recalculate the loop index - the function returns as soon splice is called.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I guess it's too late for me. ;)

Comment: I just updated my question with a link to the app, that is the only code sample I can give. I think the problem has to do with the interactions between the functions which are cued by different events, so I don't think I could recreate it in a fiddle.

Comment: You are possibly being fooled by the chrome console. If you output the array three times and open up the last array output every other output of the array will have the same values. It's not evaluated until you expand the values. Try it out. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You would really be better served by using Javascript's array methods.

Add to array:

```
this.objs.push(obj);
```

Remove from array:

```
this.objs.splice(this.objs.indexOf(obj), 1);
```

Also, note that `splice` edits the original array and returns the elements that have been removed. It's hard to tell from your limited code sample, but that might also be causing issues.

Comment: I changed everything to use push, but the issue still exists. And nothing is done with the return value, so I know thats not causing any problems