# Appending an element to an array: Differences between direct assignment and `push`?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
arr.push(Math.random());
```

and

```
arr[arr.length]=Math.random();
```

have the same result.

So, what's the difference between them? In other words, when is it better to use the former than the latter?

Comment: `arr.push()` is the more common idiom, and it's shorter.

Comment: please check this link about performance https://jsperf.com/array-direct-assignment-vs-push also there is a question which has good details in it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value .

Comment: @esertbas: That test is fundamentally flawed (and the third test case is nonsense): `array` is reused between test iterations, so `push` is doing a lot more work than assignment. Here's one that actually compares like for like and ensures that dead code optimization doesn't kick in: https://jsperf.com/simple-array-append-comparison

Answer (score 7):

> what's the difference between them

Looking at [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.push) and giving it some thought, there are at least six:

1. `push(...)` is a method call, the other is an assignment.
2. You can add multiple elements with `push`: `arr.push(one, two, three)`. To do that with assignment, you need multiple assignments. (`push` also doesn't update `length` until it's done all the work, whereas naturally multiple assignments would update it for each assignment.)
3. `push` checks to see if the array's length will become > 2<sup>53</sup>-1 and throws a `TypeError` if so; assignment does not, it just happily creates a property with a name that isn't an array index. (It's an interesting check, given that [array indexes are only allowed to be up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type). But one the spec does in *lots* of places in relation to array length.)
4. Since `arr.push(...)` looks up `push` on `arr`, it can be intercepted (by assigning a new `push` to `arr` or to `Array.prototype`). The assignment can only be intercepted on a per-property basis (using a setter for `"0"`, `"1"`, etc.) or via a `Proxy`.
5. If you're working with a Proxy for an array with a `set` trap, rather than working with the array directly, you may observe different `set` calls (because the `set` trap will presumably set the value on the underlying array directly, and so you won't see the `set` for `length`).
6. [As Redu points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42884722/157247), the result of `arr.push(value)` is the new length of the array; the result of `arr[arr.lenght] = value` is the value pushed.

> In other words, when is it better to use the former than the latter?

It's entirely up to you. Since `push` is a method call that ultimately ends up doing the same thing the assignment does (with a bit more overhead, such as the `length` check), then *in theory* on some engines or at least in some situations it may be the *tiniest bit* slower than direct assignment; but then, your direct assignment has the overhead of looking up `arr.length`. In practice, on modern engines, I see no significant difference; [test here](https://jsperf.com/simple-array-append-comparison), and any difference would be extremely unlikely to matter in the real world anyway. Other than that and #2-#6 above, it's a style choice.

Example of #5 (only works on JavaScript engines with ES2015 `Proxy` support):

```js
const a = [];
const p = new Proxy(a, {
  set(target, prop, value) {
    console.log("Proxy set called for " + prop + " = " + value);
    target[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
});
p[0] = "a";         // We don't see length set here
console.log(p[0]);
p.push("b");        // We do here, because `push` sets `length` through
                    // the proxy reference
console.log(p[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to T.J. Crowders detailed answer in real life my use of one or the other depends on one and only one factor. That's what return value i expect when i push an item to an array.

- `arr.push(item)` returns you the new length of the array.
- `arr[arr.length] = item` returns you pushed item.
- `arr.concat(item)` returns you a new array with the pushed item.
- `(arr.push(item),arr)` returns you the array with the newly pushed
  item.

In functional programming they both have their use cases. However especially the later two can introduce a huge difference and unexpected bugs to you code if you are not careful since in JS arrays are reference types.

Oh by the way since you have asked, unlike as mentioned in older books, the first two has zero effect on performance, even micro performance wise no difference can be seen anymore. They are both very fast.