# JavaScript loops and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

**I would like to know:**

1. When do you use the indexing method to assign values to a new array?
2. and; When do you use the push method?

I know you can assign a value to an array in a for loop by using indexing.

**My question is:**
I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
for (i=array_len-2;i>0;i-=2)
{
var new_arry=array[i]
}
```

... that would just return the value for `i`.  It does not store it in the new array.

but, if i do that same thing:

```
for (i=array_len-2;i>0;i-=2)
{
var new_arry=array.push(i)
}
```

it adds the new element in the array in the format of [element one , element two].

Comment: you don't need to instantiate `new_arry` inside the for loop

Comment: If you want to make a new array, neither of those code blocks will work.

Comment: The first one continually overwrites new_array with whatever is in array[i], the second one continually overwrites new_array with the return value of push(). Neither make a new array, or set an array element

Comment: A key thing to note about push vs explicit set can be seen by the difference in this output: `let a = []; a["foo"] = "bar"; console.log(a.length);`.  `length` is still 0.

Comment: What is the question? Adding values from one array to another?

Comment: I have tried formatting your post but your intention was not clear? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want new array to story every two indexs of array. 
for (i=array_len-2;i>0;i-=2)
new_arry=array[i]

that only stores the indexs of array where i is

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows, how you should use the index `i` and the `push` method.

```js
var myArray = ["hello", "world", "welcome", "javascript", "user"];
var newArray = new Array();

for(var i=myArray.length-2; i>0; i-=2) {
  newArray.push(myArray[i]);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

A `push()` simply add anything you pass as argument to an array.
Index `i` are used to identify the "index location" on an array.

Answer (score 1):

Either way works, just create an empty array outside the loop. Use the incrementing variable as you progress through each iteration (loop). Avoid using keyword `new` when making arrays, it's 99% better to use literal ex. `var array = [];`

Keep in mind that the loop in your examples go backward (`-=2`) and it's unusual in that that it stops early (`i=array_len-2;i>0;`), normally a loop is set at full length (`i=array_len` which is derived from `var array_len = array.length` most likely). So this unorthodox loop will only add 2 extra elements if the array is only 4 to 5 in length (I might be off...).

### Demo

```js
// Fill array by push()
var arr1 = [];

for (let i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr1.push(i);
}

console.log(arr1);

// Fill array by assignment
var arr2 = [];

for (let i=0; i< 5; i++) {
  arr2[i] = i;
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use indexes for anything that should be in a specific index if it doesn't matter you can probably use `push()` which will return the new length and it is said on this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value) that is faster than indexes.