# Unable to create an array dynamically using foEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

In the below code when I console the values of `calculateTips()`, I am getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

```
let tipCal = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  calculateTips: function() {
    this.tips = [];
    this.finalValue = [];
    (this.bills).forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (item < 50) {
        this.tips[index] = (item * .2);
      } else if (item >= 50 && item < 200) {
        this.tips[index] = (item * .15);
      } else {
        this.tips[index] = (item * .1);
      }
    });
    return this.tips;

  }
}
```

I am unable to understand why I am getting this error because according to me I am doing the right thing. Please help.

Comment: `this` inside of your `.forEach` function isn't referring to your object. You can use an arrow function instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note. First, using index notation instead of `Array.prototype.push` isn't very common, as far as I've seen. Since you're building `this.tips` from scratch, you can use `this.tips.push(...)`. Using `push` can sometimes have better performance as well. See here: [Why is array.push sometimes faster than array[n] = value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614126/why-is-array-push-sometimes-faster-than-arrayn-value)

Secondly, yes, the use of a `function` changes the context of `this`, so `this` inside your `forEach` callback is referring to the callback function and not `tipCal`. Using an arrow function as has been suggested will retain the context of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result by doing this. Use it according to your need.

```
var num = 10,
  dynar = [...Array(num)].map((_,i) => ++i+"");
console.log(dynar);
```

> Output: [   "1",   "2",   "3",   "4",   "5",   "6",   "7",   "8",
>   "9",   "10" ]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.forEach` callback function with `=>`([arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) function

Try this:

```js
  let tipCal = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    calculateTips: function () {
      this.tips = [];
      this.finalValue = [];
      (this.bills).forEach((item, index)=> {
        if (item < 50) {
          this.tips[index] = (item * .2);
        } else if (item >= 50 && item < 200) {
          this.tips[index] = (item * .15);
        } else {
          this.tips[index] = (item * .1);
        }
      });
      return this.tips;

    }
  }
  console.log(tipCal.calculateTips())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this because function inside a function change the `this` keyword.

the `.forEach(function(item, index) {` live inside `calculateTips: function() {`.
Try to use the arrow function, so it's will be `.forEach((item, index) => {`.

The arrow function will not change the `this` keyword.

So it will return..

> (5) [18.599999999999998, 9.600000000000001, 26.8, 27, 8.4]